# Difficulty Making Debian Server Public Facing

Tags: debian

I am trying to make my server public facing however, it seems to a little harder than I thought. I have been given 4 IP address off my ISP, 79.xx.x.204 - 79.xx.x.207, with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.252 (ISP has confirmed the subnet mask). From what I remember the first and last addresses of a subnet are not usable as they are the broadcast address and, from what I recall, the gateway address. However, this configuration isn't working.

I spoke to my ISP to determine if the 79.xx.x.204 address is the default gateway, however, they flat out refused to answer and stated they merely deliver internet services and do not get involved with other uses's networks.

The system I am trying to setup is a Linux Debian and, if it helps in anyway, here is my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp0s31f6 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
address 79.xx.x.206
netmask 255.255.255.252
gateway 79.xx.x.204
bridge_ports enp0s31f6
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
```

The reason I am setting up a bridge is so I can, in the future, use the bridge for VMs with their own public IP addresses.

The server is plugged into the LAN port on my router. I have flashed the router with openwrt and put the server on it's own VLAN to segregate it from my internal network.

Any assistance would be really appreciated.

Regards, Carl

Comment: What settings do you get if you pull a DHCP address from your ISP?

Comment: I've checked for DHCP settings inside my router, but I've not been able to find them. All I can find is the WAN IP and DNS server IPs.The DHCP settings I get from my router are 192.168.1.140, netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.1.1